# Existence of partial derivatives implies existence of the derivative under this condition?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

How to prove the following? Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{R}$ have all partial derivatives (e.g., the partial derivative of the 1st coordinate is defined as $\lim_{t \xrightarrow{}0} \frac{f(x+te_{1}) - f(x) }{t}$ where $e_{1}$ is the unit vector with only the 1st coordinate being $1$, others $0$) in the open set $U$. $x \in U$. Also,

$\lim_{t \xrightarrow{}0} \frac{f(x+td) - f(x) - \langle \nabla f(x), td \rangle}{t} = 0$ uniformly for $\lVert d \rVert \leq 1$, that is, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$, s.t. $\lVert \frac{f(x+td) - f(x) - \langle \nabla f(x), td \rangle}{t}\rVert < \epsilon$ for all $|t| < \delta$ and for all $\lVert d \rVert \leq 1$. Then, $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

So I want to show, for some $l$, $\lim_{\lVert h\rVert \xrightarrow{} 0 } \frac{f(x + h) - f(x) - \langle l, h \rangle}{\lVert h\rVert} = 0$ and so by definition $f$ is differentiable. I want to take $l = \nabla f(x)$.

(This is a remark on page 7 of the book Foundations of Optimization. The $\langle \nabla f(x), td \rangle$ in the book is typed as $\langle \nabla f(x), d \rangle$ which I guess may be a typo?)

Comment: I don't see what you need to prove. It just looks like a statement to me. Yes, that is a typo. You need to learn the definition of *differentiability* and I'm guessing that the question is why the uniformity condition implies differentiability at $x$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks that's what I'm asking.

Comment: OK, so the first step is to write out the definition and what needs to be proved!

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks I just added the definition of differentiation

Comment: Indeed, you take $l=\nabla f(x)$. Perhaps it would help to write $td = h$?

Comment: @TedShifrin When I tried to prove the converse (that is, differentiability implies this uniform convergence) this helps, because I can multiply the $t$ in the denominator by $d$ and multiply the numerator by $d$, whose absolute value $\leq 1$. Then the uniform convergence follows. But now, doing so (viewing $h$ as $td$ in the formula of differentiability) results in a term $\frac{1}{\lVert d \rVert}$

Comment: Good point. Why don't you restrict to the sphere $\|d\| = 1$? (Namely, just take $d = v/\|v\|$.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh right... I could have taken $|t| = \lVert h \rVert$. Many thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should write a brief answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Ted Shifrin !

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Assume there exists $\delta > 0$, s.t. $\lVert \frac{f(x+td) - f(x) - \langle \nabla f(x), td \rangle}{t}\rVert < \epsilon$ for all $|t| < \delta$ and for all $\lVert d \rVert \leq 1$.

Consider, $\frac{f(x + h) - f(x) - \langle \nabla f(x), h \rangle}{\lVert h\rVert}$. If we can show for all $\lVert h \rVert < \delta$, the norm of this term is smaller than $\epsilon$, then we are done by the definition of differentiability.

For $\lVert h \rVert \neq 0$, let $h = td$, where $t = \lVert h \rVert$ and $d$ the unit vector. Now $\lVert \frac{f(x + h) - f(x) - \langle \nabla f(x), h \rangle}{\lVert h\rVert} \rVert = \lVert \frac{f(x+td) - f(x) - \langle \nabla f(x), td \rangle}{td} \rVert = \lVert \frac{f(x+td) - f(x) - \langle \nabla f(x), td \rangle}{t} \rVert < \epsilon$ where the inequality follows from the assumption